# Efficient algorithm to handle system of changing probabilities

Tags: python, algorithm, redis

I need help in formulating an algorithm. I have a social networking app built in python with a redis backend. One of the features is an advertising server that advertisers can use to create and serve ads to site users.

Advertisers buy clicks. Cost per click is not fixed. One advertiser may pay 1 cent/click, another may pay 2 cents/click, etc. The more an advertiser pays, the greater the probability of her advertisement being displayed. I.e., higher paying advertisers get clicks *faster*, all else being equal.

E.g. imagine advertiser 1 paid $10 for 1000 clicks, advertiser 2 paid $20 for 1000 clicks and advertiser 3 paid $30 for 1000 clicks. All else equal, at each ad impression, advertiser 1's ad will have a 1/6 probability of appearing, advertiser 2's ad will have a 2/6 probability of appearing and advertiser 3's ad will have a 3/6 probability of appearing. If a 4th advertiser was added to the mix, the probabilities will revise. Once an advertiser's designated clicks are reached, she's taken out of the mix and the probabilities revise again.

How can this be modeled in an efficient algorithm?

---

One reason I get stumped when trying to model this is because upon adding (or subtracting) an advertiser, the whole system's probabilities are revised on the fly. I haven't been able to wrap my head around this; hopefully experts can help out.

Comment: You could have a list that consists of 10 entries of 'ad1' 20 entries of 'ad2' etc.  Do `random.sample` on that list to choose your advertiser.  Then have a dict that maps `'ad1'` to the count of ads clicked.  when an ad is clicked, increment the counter and then just `del` the key in the dictionary and recompile the list to modify advertisers.

Comment: This seems like it would be unfair for the advertisers who bought ads earlier, as they would have paid for a certain probability of the ad showing, then have that probability decrease after they paid...

Comment: How many advertisers are we talking about? How often do their ads 'run out'? It seems that this shouldn't be difficult to calculate each time the set of advertisers changes.

Comment: keep the cumulative sum and the individual value seperate and calculate probabilities on the fly(i.e. when required). a=10,b=20,c=30 gives sum=60. p(a)=10/60,p(b)=20/60,p(c)=30/60. d came with d=20, so sum becomes 80. p(d) becomes 20/80. others will also change since total sum is changed now. You can also maintain heap to find top k prob. at any time in case required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an advertiser buying ad spots, I'm personally unsure I would want to pay for an uncertain probability my ad would be shown. The closest to reasonable thing I can imagine, (which may be what you were thinking of anyway) is to only guarantee that those who paid the same rate get the same probability. An efficient way to do this would be to keep a cumulative sum of the rates paid to give your random range:

```
cumsum, rate, company

1,  1,  A
2,  1,  B
4,  2,  C
8,  4,  D
```

if you generate a random number from 0 to 7 (or 1 to 8) you can do a binary search (O log(n)) to determine which ad should be shown.

If you keep the companies sorted by rate, you could probably even do better than (O log(n))... maybe

adding and subtracting companies would be relatively simple: add (or subtract) a line for the company and the rate, then recalculate cumsum.